# (Java Minecraft 1.14) Call SelectedItem Damage Tag

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to call the Damage tag of an item in my selected hand, but cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it!

If there needs to be a work around in place for this I would be entirely happy to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example code:
run initialy: `/scoreboard objectives add damage dummy`
run repeatedly: `/execute as @a store result score @s damage run data get entity @s SelectedItem.tag.Damage`
this stores for each player the damage of the item in his hand in the scoreboard `damage`.

Comment: You know that you can edit posts, right? You don't need to delete and redo them.

Comment: This totally solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @FabianRöling: yes, I know, but when I was writing, I reloaded the page and I didn't knew, that this would post my answer, so I wrote along and when I posted my real answer, I noticed that the old one had been posted already, so I deleted it.